# How Sign/Verify Litecoin message in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, litecoin

For a day there was a task to sign and verify message in Litecoin wallet. A couple of days of searches did not work, so I had to rewrite a few of my functions using the library [bitcoin](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/issues) for signing and verifying messages. Special thanks to the guys from the [electrum](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum) for their achievements that helped to find solutions. Ok, fewer words more code ...

```
import bitcoin


class SignVerify:

    def sign(self, address, message, private_key):
        if self.check_if_not_message(message):
            set_data = self.sign_message_with_private_key(private_key, address, message)
            return set_data
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Incorrect private key.')

    def verify(self, message, signature, public_key):
        if self.check_if_not_message(signature):

            return self.ecdsa_verify(message, signature, public_key)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Signature is empty.')

    def sign_message_with_private_key(self, private_key, address, message):
        message_in_byte = message.encode()

        return self.ecdsa_sign(message_in_byte, private_key)

    @staticmethod
    def check_if_not_message(message):
        if message is None or not message or message == ' ':
            return

        return True

    @staticmethod
    def litecoin_sig_hash(message):
        padded = b"\x19Litecoin Signed Message:\n" + bitcoin.num_to_var_int(
            len(message)) + bitcoin.from_string_to_bytes(message)
        return bitcoin.bin_dbl_sha256(padded)

    def ecdsa_sign(self, msg, priv):
        v, r, s = bitcoin.ecdsa_raw_sign(self.litecoin_sig_hash(msg), priv)
        sig = bitcoin.encode_sig(v, r, s)
        assert self.ecdsa_verify(msg, sig,
                                    bitcoin.privtopub(priv)), "Bad Sig!\t %s\nv = %d\n,r = %d\ns = %d" % (sig, v, r, s)
        return sig

    def ecdsa_verify(self, msg, sig, pub):
        return bitcoin.ecdsa_raw_verify(self.litecoin_sig_hash(msg), bitcoin.decode_sig(sig), pub)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    message = 'LNXKMg8NTd5XLAF2n3HNMYYbyZB6KR7E4x'
    address = 'LNXKMg8NTd5XLAF2n3HNMYYbyZB6KR7E4x'
    privkey = 'T8vwiYErLrsWVytCzaFtQkaYgMYRN2qi4XaWYveeEVBfiiepnNjE'
    public_key = '034835d15daca879dd91689e4f2c0650d495bdde0fdb4edb8ceb909830cdf7f26f'
    a = SignVerify()
    signature = a.sign(address=address, message=message, private_key=privkey)
    print('sign => ', signature)
    print('verify => ', a.verify(message=message, signature=signature, public_key=public_key))
```

I hope someone will help )))

Comment: I do hope you don't ever receive money with the address you posted here... That aside, what's wrong with your code? If there anything not working? From your post I only see an introduction and a large block of code, but not a question.

Comment: This is just a hint to those who, like me, were looking for a solution to their problem. A address purse randomly from the site https://iancoleman.io/bip39/